How do I resolve an intermittent oracle error when trying to call an external dll: ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent?
I've been seeing an intermittent oracle error for a few weeks when trying to call an external procedure/dll. The message received is:

ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent

Has anyone else encountered this? If so, what steps were taken to resolve it? I am using oracle standard edition 19c with latest patch, 19.24.0 and I'm on a windows host.

UPDATE: Patch 36551493 does not resolve the issue. The only recommendation given by Oracle is to rollback RU 36521936.
UPDATE: Oracle has provided a hotfix with Patch 36551493: https://updates.oracle.com/download/36551493.html
We've been encountering the same issue, at first it was only noticed in a test environment, but then quickly it was seen on all prod & non-prod environments. It is a bug in the latest database patch, RU 36521936. I submitted the issue to Oracle and they are working on a fix as we speak. Typically Oracle would update issues on their RU known issues page here, but it is not listed to date.
As you stated it appears to be intermittent, which made this very difficult to troubleshoot. The error usually occurs when you establish a new connection to the oracle instance. We have a geodatabase installed so we are using dll's provided by esri to do spatial computations, sample error below:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select sde.st_point (0,0,0) from dual
Error report -
ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 12
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_POINT", line 181

Can you go to your %ORACLE_HOME%/hs/trace directory and check to see if you have occurrences of the NCR code 1009 error in any trace files generated there? If so you are most likely suffering from the same issue, a bug in the latest database patch for oracle 19c on windows. The interim solution is to rollback the patch.

I rolledback and the issue went away, I will submit issue to oracle, cheers

@ChipDouglas We are suffering from the same issue and opened SR to Oracle Support, but they did not admit that it is a bug, so we are in the middle of nowhere.
Тhe interesting thing in our case is that on one server we have an issue and on another we don't, and the configurations of both servers are exactly the same.
Have you made any progress in your SR to Oracle?

@ZhivkoZhekov Are your instances hosted on windows also?
